# function based index using concat SQL

Tags: mysql

Am a bit confused about function based index using concat in SQL.

I had a question where I needed to " Create a function-based index that could potentially increase the speed of the query ", and the query was about how many actors share the same first and last name.

My solution for that is:

```
Create index Fname_Lname on ACTOR (CONCAT (first_name , last_name));
```

I believe it works, but am not sure about how it works and the functionally which gives it more speed than normal query.

Hope to get some help soon.

Thanks

Database Scheme below...

[Database Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8CFn.jpg)

Comment: Why is this tagged "mysql"?

Comment: You should show us the problem query and table structure.

Comment: @rlanvin and  .. The image in addd now

Comment: SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, COUNT(*) 
    FROM ACTOR A
    Group by first_name, last_name
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1;   .. this i my query for finding same first and last name

Answer (score 0):

The concat is not necessary, you just specify the 2 columns, and that will do what you are looking for.

```
 Create index Fname_Lname on ACTOR (first_name , last_name);
```

You can do this since the name combination are not unique. This wouldn't work for Primary keys or unique keys, however.

Comment: but as shown in the database scheme I added in the question .. what does this index do differently ..? and does it makes a difference if we add concat..? @Octopi

Comment: In essence, mysql doesnt need you to cat the values in order to acheive what you are doing. it sort of does it itself in order to create the index. In essence, a column doesnt exist where the first and last names are concatedd. This is however how you would speed up searches on first and lastname.